# Extract GUID from ActiveX COM DLL using Python

Tags: python, dll, com, activex, guid

How would you extract the GUID of an ActiveX COM DLL using only Python in a cross-platform manner?

I ran across `pythoncom`, which comes with `pywin32`. It has a `LoadTypeLib` function which can do just that:

```
import pythoncom
dll = pythoncom.LoadTypeLib("C:\\path\to\\my.dll")
print str(dll.GetLibAttr()[0])
```

This is better than my current solution which relies on an external CLI application, however a cross-platform solution would be even better as I don't believe pywin32 can be installed on a Linux CI easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the wonderful `comtypes` package:

```
from comtypes.typeinfo import LoadTypeLibEx
lib = LoadTypeLibEx("C:\\path\to\\my.dll")
print lib.GetLibAttr().guid
```

The code is effectively the same; it literally calls the same `LoadTypeLib` from `OleAut32` so it is Windows-only, however `comtypes` is installable through pip which makes the distribution easier.